# Vivado 2016.1: Upon synthesis it is removing useful logic. Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, ram, synthesis, vivado

I am currently working on building a soft core processor, and I have been having trouble synthesizing a Verilog Implemented RAM and other sequential elements. I decided to work individually on each section of the processor in order to find out what´s going on, no luck yet I'm afraid. The circuit I tried to synthesize does mainly 2 things: Fills memory with data driven by a clock; after the memory is filled with data a flag will indicate this sending a signal to an external processor, which will send another signal called ready in order to read and store memory content.

These are the modules:

> ### TOP MODULE

```
module DATATEST(clk,JRED,led,jd,ja);
 
 input clk;
 input  JRED;
 output [1:0] led;
 output [7:0] ja;
 output [1:0] jd;
 
 
 
 wire RESP,FLAG,RDY,SENT,CL;
 wire [7:0] DATA;
 
 wire BFLAG, BCL,BFL,BL;
 wire WD;
 wire [31:0] MR,MW,FAD,LAD,AD;
 
 assign CL = clk;
 assign RDY = JRED;
 assign led[0] = BL;
 assign led[1] = SENT;
 assign ja = DATA;
 assign jd[0] = RESP; 
 assign jd[1] = FLAG;
 
  fill_mem FM1(.clock(BCL),.flag(FLAG),.out(MW),.ad(FAD));

  not_gate NG1(.I(BFLAG),.O(WD));

  mux MUX1(.a(FAD),.b(LAD),.c(BFL),.o(AD));

  data_memory DM1(.address(AD),.wr_da(MW),.mem_write(WD),.mem_read(FLAG),.re_da(MR));

  com_out CM1(.ready(RDY),.flag(BFL),.in(MR),.out(DATA),.sent(SENT),.response(RESP),
  .address(LAD));
 

  buffer F1(.in(FLAG),.out(BFLAG));

  buffer F2(.in(FLAG),.out(BFL));

  buffer F3(.in(FLAG),.out(BL));

  buffer C1(.in(CL),.out(BCL));
  
endmodule
`
```

> ### OTHER MODULES:

```
module data_memory(address,wr_da,mem_write,mem_read,re_da);
 
 parameter SIZE = 16;
 input [31:0] address;
 input [31:0] wr_da;
 input mem_write;
 input mem_read;
 output [31:0] re_da;
  
 reg [7:0] MEM [0:SIZE-1];
 
 assign re_da = (mem_read == 1) ? {MEM[address],MEM[address+1],MEM[address+2],MEM[address+3]}:0 ;
 
 always @ (wr_da, address)
  begin
 
  
 
    if (mem_write == 1)
    begin
     MEM[address] = wr_da[31:24];
     MEM[address+1] = wr_da[23:16];
     MEM[address+2] = wr_da[15:8];
     MEM[address+3] = wr_da[7:0];
    end

   
  
  end

module mux(a,b,c,o);

 parameter N = 32;
 input [N-1:0] a;
 input [N-1:0] b;
 input c;
 output reg [N-1:0] o = 0;

 always @*
 begin
 
  o = 0;
 
  case (c)
   
   0: o = a;
   1: o = b;
  
   default: o = 0;
  
  endcase

 end
 
endmodule

module com_out(ready,flag,in,out,sent,response,address);

 input ready;
 input flag;
 input [31:0] in;
 output reg [7:0] out;
 output reg sent;
 output reg [31:0] address = 0;
 output  response;
 reg SINT = 0;
 reg COUNT = 0;
 reg R = 0; 
 reg [15:0] SEND = 0;
 wire  [7:0] DATA [3:0];
 
 assign DATA[0] = in[31:24];
 assign DATA[1] = in[23:16];
 assign DATA[2] = in[15:8];
 assign DATA[3] = in[7:0];
 
 assign response = (R == 1) ? 1:0;
  
 always @ (ready)
 begin
  out = 0;
  
  if (ready == 1)
  begin
  
   if ((flag==1) && (SINT==0))
    begin
   
     out = DATA[SEND];
     R = 1;
     SEND = SEND+1;
   
     if (SEND==4)
     begin
      address = address + 4;
      SEND = 0; 
      COUNT = COUNT + 1; 
     end
     else
      address = address;
      
    end
   
    else
     out = 0;
   
   end
   
   else 
    R = 0;

   
   if (COUNT == 4)
   begin
    sent = 1;
    SINT = 1;
   end
   
   else
   begin
    sent = 0;
    SINT = 0;
   end
 end
 
endmodule


module fill_mem (clock,flag,out,ad);
 
 input clock;
 output reg flag = 0;
 output reg [31:0] out = 0; 
 output  [31:0] ad ;
 reg [31:0] COMP = 0;
 reg [31:0] COND = 0;
 assign ad = COND;
 
 always @ (negedge clock)
 begin
  
  COMP = COMP + 4;
  COND = COMP - 4;
  
  case  (COND)
   0 : out = 32'hACDECACA; 
   4 : out =  32'hACAFECAD; 
   8: out = 32'hCAFEBEEF; 
   12: out = 32'hDEADCAFE; 
   default: out = 0; 
  endcase
  
  
  
  if (COMP >= 20)
   flag = 1;
  else
   flag = 0;
   
 end
endmodule
```

Even tho simulation works perfectly, synthesis throws some warning messages:

> ### WARNING MESSAGES

```
[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[31]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[27]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[26]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[25]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[24]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[23]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[20]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[19]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[18]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[11]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[10]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[9]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[7]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[5]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[4]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[2]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[1]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/COND_reg[0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[0][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[1][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[2][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[3][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[4][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[5][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[6][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[7][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[8][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[9][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[10][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[11][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[12][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[13][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[14][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[15][3]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/COMP_reg[0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/COMP_reg[1]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/COND_reg[1]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (FM1/out_reg[8]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[0][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[2][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[4][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[6][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[8][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[10][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[12][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (DM1/MEM_reg[14][0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (CM1/address_reg[0]) is unused and will be removed from module DATATEST.
```

And I wish I understood why, since all the elements are actually used.

So, I would be very grateful if could help me to figure out what the problem is and how to solve it. Thanks in advance :D T.T

Comment: You know that synthesis creates HW, so if you are filling the memory with some constant data, and not reading from it, it will be optimized away by the synthesis tool. I really don't understand what you are trying to do, this is not HDL, this is SW thinking in sequential terms.

Comment: The thing is that I do actually read that data. com__out module extracts this info once the memory is filled, This is for FPGA functionality test. And yah, it is sequential, because it is synchronized to clock signal. This is for a processor, processors work sequentially (unless you use pipelining, which I'm not using, but they still read instructions sequentially).
So yes, I need it to be filled first. and them read its content, since a memory should not be read and written at the same time.

Comment: The memory is filled within 4 clock cycles. Once the fill_mem module has finished this task it will raise a flag (which is actually an output), and send this signal to some muxes and com_out. Now com_out is able to extract the info controlled by the signal ready (an FPGA input). I plan on extracting this info with a Micro controller to do some other things, that's why I need it to be that sequential too.

Comment: But once again, if you consider I am doing it the wrong way, please tell me how should I. That's why I came here asking for help after all n.n

Comment: FYI you got combinational loops in `com_out`. Also `always @ (ready)` will create functional mismatch between simulation and synthesized circuit. The full sensitivity list must be specified to avoid the mismatch, or use `always @*`. Latches and flops should be assigned with non-blocking (`<=`) assignments, not blocking (`=`) assignments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. So, if I wanted to use the comb. loop how should I proceed? I mean, I need a counter.  The problem is what you tell me about the always block. I need it only to work with ready. This can be achieved by using posege or negedge, but I had some trouble doing so, cuz I need a signal to react to both pos and neg and multidriven signals are not allowed. What do you suggest I should do? :)

Comment: (Yah I read synthesis assumes that always blocks have @*)

Comment: Oh I think I've got an idea :D @Greg . if I use always @ ( posedge ready or negedge ready) will that solve the problem with comb loop? :) Also using <= of course :p

Comment: Btw, question, should I use <= for every reg type? or may outputs use =?

Comment: @Richter , Nope `always @ ( posedge ready or negedge ready)` will not synthesis the way you want. I would suggest stillting the logic into two always blocks one `@(posedge read)` sequential logic the other `@*` for combinational (a `reg` must assigned in no more that one always block). `<=` should be not be used on all reg types, `reg` does not mean hardware register, it just means it is assigned within a procedural block and not an assign statement. You need to review RTL coding practices before trying to fix your current code.

Comment: Yah, @Greg I have been reading a book about it, mainly they recommend using non-blocking assignments with latches and flip flops as you say, but depending on what you want to do using blocking assignments might be the way . Thanks a lot for your help n.n Btw, I was able to find a way to keep the synthesizer from taking logic away, just used (*dont_touch = "true"*) before  the declaration of the varialble I wanted to keep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works perfectly now. I used don_touch on some things, modified some code on RAM, and decided to make a different output and TOP module in order to achieve a simpler way to test on FPGA. Basically, the fill_mem module fills the memory with data (as the name suggests), then the memory is read by another module which is taken to some leds on the board, where stored bytes can be checked. The reading address is selected with switches.

> ### TOP MODULE

```
module RAM_LEDS( clk, sw, led,lr,lb);

 input clk;
 input [3:0] sw;
 output [3:0] led;
 output [3:0] lr;
 output [0:0] lb;




     wire FLAG;


     wire [3:0] EXT;

     wire WD;
     wire [31:0] MR,MW;
     wire [4:0] RESU, A/*,B*/,FAD,LAD,AD,TA;
     wire [7:0] LO;

     assign led = LO[3:0];
     assign lr =  LO[7:4];  
     assign lb[0] = FLAG;
     assign EXT = sw;


    fill_mem FM1(.a(A),.out(MW),.ad(FAD));

    adder_oi #(5) A1(.p(A),.result(RESU));

    not_gate NG1(.I(FLAG),.O(WD));


    mux #(5) MUX1(.a(FAD),.b(LAD),.c(FLAG),.o(AD));

    bus #(5) B1(.clk(clk),.I(RESU),.O(A));

    data_memory DM1(.clock(clk),.address(AD),.wr_da(MW),.mem_write(WD),.mem_read(FLAG),.re_da(MR));

    peripheral P1(.a(FAD),.flag(FLAG));

    extend EX1(.I(EXT),.O(TA));

    switching S1(.ai(TA),.data(MR),.leds(LO),.ao(LAD));

endmodule
```

> ### Instantiated Modules

### HW USED TO READ from RAM

```
module peripheral(a,flag);
parameter A = 5;
input [A-1:0] a;
output flag;

assign flag = (a == 20) ? 1:0;
assign flag = (a == 20) ? 1:0;

endmodule

module extend(I,O);

 input [3:0] I;
 output [4:0] O;

 assign O = {1'b0,I};

endmodule

module switching(ai,data,leds,ao);

input [4:0] ai;
input [31:0] data;
output reg [7:0] leds;
output reg [4:0] ao;

wire [7:0] D [0:3];
assign D[0] = data[7:0];
assign D[1] = data[15:8];
assign D[2] = data[23:16];
assign D[3] = data[31:24];

always @*
begin

case (ai)
0,1,2,3: ao = 0;
4,5,6,7: ao = 4;
8,9,10,11: ao = 8;
12,13,14,15: ao = 12;
default: ao = 0;
endcase

leds = D[ai%4];


end
endmodule
```

### HW USED TO FILL RAM

```
module fill_mem (a,out,ad);
 parameter A = 5;
 input [A-1:0] a;
 output [31:0] out; 
 output  [A-1:0] ad;
 (* dont_touch = "true" *) reg [31:0] O = 0;
 (* dont_touch = "true" *) reg [A-1:0] AR = 0;
 assign out = O;
 assign ad = AR;

 always @*
 begin


  case  (a)
   0: begin AR = 0; O = 32'h00000000;; end
   4: begin AR = 4; O = 32'hFFF00F00;  end
   8:  begin AR =  8; O = 32'h9669C33C; end
   12: begin AR = 12; O = 32'hF173371F;  end
   16: begin AR = 16; O = 32'hFFFFFFFF; end
   default: begin AR = 20; O = 0;  end 
  endcase

 end
endmodule

module bus(clk,I,O);
parameter N = 32;
input clk;
input [N-1:0] I;
output [N-1:0] O;
(* dont_touch = "true" *)reg [N-1:0] C = 0;
assign O = C;

always @(posedge clk)
begin

C = I;

end
endmodule

module adder_oi(p,result); //PC+4

 parameter N =32;
 input [N-1:0] p;
 output [N-1:0] result;

 assign result = p + 4;

endmodule
```

### MISC.

```
module mux(a,b,c,o);

 parameter N = 32;
 input [N-1:0] a;
 input [N-1:0] b;
 input c;
 output reg [N-1:0] o = 0;

 always @*
 begin

  o = 0;

  case (c)

   0: o = a;
   1: o = b;

   default: o = 0;

  endcase

 end

endmodule
```

### DA RAM ITSELF

```
module data_memory(clock,address,wr_da,mem_write,mem_read,re_da);

 parameter SIZE = 24;
 parameter A = 5;
 input [A-1:0] address;
 input clock;
 input [31:0] wr_da;
 input mem_write;
 input mem_read;

 output  [31:0] re_da;

 (* ram_style = "auto" *) reg [31:0] MEM [0:SIZE-1];

 assign re_da = (mem_read) ? MEM[address]:0;

 always @(negedge clock)
  begin



    if  ((mem_write) &&(!mem_read))
    begin
     MEM[address] <= wr_da;

    end


  end


 endmodule
```

This is it. Now the only think that remains is to test the complete processor.

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep the synthesizer from removing "unused" logic I used this statement before the declaration of the variable I wanted to keep:

```
EXAMPLE: 
(*dont_touch = "true"*) output reg [7:0] out;
(*dont_touch = "true"*) reg COUNT = 0;
......
```

Thanks to those who bothered to try to elaborate things I did not understand well.

Comment: This is the equivalent of ignoring a compilation warning and overriding it saying "I know what I'm doing".

Comment: I know that. Once I test the code in FPGA I will find out whether I am right or not. It is better than having the logic removed, that way the circuit wouldn't  work either.

Comment: And by the way, why only criticizing? I mean, you could just help and tell me how should I do it instead @dave . For me it doesn't make any sense to say someone else is wrong if you don't correct them xD I have been learning all of this on my own with no one to help me, And now, I try calling for help and this is what happens XD Welp, life is ironic at times. Have a good day dave.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, but I know that this isn't it.  If you had a smaller example showing this behaviour then I might be better placed to show how to solve it.  My comment isn't for you but it is for the next person who sees the same error message and wants to know how to fix it then I want them to know that this isn't the correct answer.

Comment: mmm I understand your point, I made it work that way tho. FPGA test successful n.n I made some modifications on the code tho, due to the synthesizer not inferring the RAM correctly. But don't touch worked fine for the rest. Maybe that is not the right answer for every project, but it solved part of my problem :) So, keep an open mind n.n as i will too, since there is also certain truth in your words.@dave